# Help building and running a Java project with Maven

Tags: java, build, maven, classpath

I want to try out the example code from this article: [Load Recovery.gov Grant Data into a CouchDB Database](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/305-load-recovery-gov-grant-data-into-a-couchdb-database/).  I'm familiar with the Java language but I know nothing about the Maven build system.

I've managed to build the project by running 'mvn package', but I get the following when trying to run it:

```
djm@surfer:~/source/sample-parse$ java -cp target/sample-parse-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.discursive.sample.parse.LoadingGrants
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpEntity
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Do I need to do something else to set up my CLASSPATH properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You built your jar correctly but when you are running the code you need to add the classpath to the jar containing `org.apache.httpcomponents`. If you want to package it as one jar then use the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) `jar-with-dependencies`.

By the way in case you did not know this, maven by convention downloads the repository jar files to the local repository under your `.m2\repository` folder. You should be able to locate `org.apache.httpcomponents` there.

Comment: might want to add a link to the assembly plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

Comment: Yes I was in the process of adding that link.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  For now I kludged it by just jamming all the jars from `~/.m2/repository` into the `CLASSPATH`.  I'll work on figuring out how `jar-with-dependencies` works.

Comment: You are welcome. Once you get the hang of it you will love maven. I have never looked back after making the transition from ant.